# Expand/Collapse Lollipop toolbar animation (Telegram app)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-toolbar, android-7.0-nougat

I'm trying to figure out how the expand/collapse animation of the toolbar is done. If you have a look at the Telegram app settings, you will see that there is a listview and the toolbar. When you scroll down, the toolbar collapse, and when you scroll up it expands. There is also the animation of the profile pic and the FAB. Does anyone have any clue on that? Do you think they built all the animations on top of it? Maybe I'm missing something from the new APIs or the support library.

I noticed the same behaviour on the Google calendar app, when you open the Spinner (I don't think it's a spinner, but it looks like): The toolbar expands and when you scroll up, it collapse.

Just to clearify: I don't need the QuickReturn method. I know that probably Telegram app is using something similar. The exact method that I need is the Google Calendar app effect. I've tried with

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

and the expand method works pretty well. But obviously, If I scroll up the ListView, the toolbar doesn't collapse.

I've also thought about adding a `GestureListener` but I want to know if there are any APIs or simpler methods of achieving this.

If there are none, I think I will go with the `GestureListener`. Hopefully to have a smooth effect of the Animation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Edit :**

Since the release of the Android Design support library, there's an easier solution. Check [joaquin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31074173/3108590)

--

Here's how I did it, there probably are many other solutions but this one worked for me.

1. First of all, you have to use a `Toolbar` with a transparent background. The expanding & collapsing `Toolbar` is actually a **fake** one that's under the transparent `Toolbar`. (you can see on the first screenshot below - the one with the margins - that this is also how they did it in Telegram).

   We only keep the actual `Toolbar` for the `NavigationIcon` and the overflow `MenuItem`.

   [image: 1. Transparent Toolbar - 2. Expanded header - 3. Collapsed header]
2. Everything that's in the red rectangle on the second screenshot (ie the fake `Toolbar` and the `FloatingActionButton`) is actually **a header** that you add to the settings `ListView` (or `ScrollView`).

   So you have to create a layout for this header in a separate file that could look like this :

   ```
    <!-- The headerView layout. Includes the fake Toolbar & the FloatingActionButton -->

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/header_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
           android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
           android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

           <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/header_infos_container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:padding="16dp">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/header_picture"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                   android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/header_title"
                   style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header_picture"
                   android:text="Toolbar Title"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/header_subtitle"
                   style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/header_title"
                   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header_picture"
                   android:text="Toolbar Subtitle"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

           </RelativeLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>

       <FloatingActionButton
           android:id="@+id/header_fab"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_open_in_browser"/>

   </FrameLayout>
   ```

   (Note that you can use negative margins/padding for the fab to be straddling on 2 `Views`)
3. Now comes the interesting part. In order to animate the expansion of our fake `Toolbar`, we implement the `ListView` `onScrollListener`.

   ```
   // The height of your fully expanded header view (same than in the xml layout)
   int headerHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
   // The height of your fully collapsed header view. Actually the Toolbar height (56dp)
   int minHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.action_bar_height);
   // The left margin of the Toolbar title (according to specs, 72dp)
   int toolbarTitleLeftMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_left_margin);
   // Added after edit
   int minHeaderTranslation;

   private ListView listView;

   // Header views
   private View headerView;
   private RelativeLayout headerContainer;
   private TextView headerTitle;
   private TextView headerSubtitle;
   private FloatingActionButton headerFab;


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_fragment, container, false);
       listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

       // Init the headerHeight and minHeaderTranslation values

       headerHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
       minHeaderTranslation = -headerHeight + 
           getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.action_bar_height);

       // Inflate your header view
       headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, listview, false);

       // Retrieve the header views
       headerContainer = (RelativeLayout) headerView.findViewById(R.id.header_container);
       headerTitle = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
       headerSubtitle = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.header_subtitle);
       headerFab = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.header_fab);;

       // Add the headerView to your listView
       listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);

       // Set the onScrollListener
       listView.setOnScrollListener(this);        

       // ...

       return rootView;
   }

   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
   {
       // Do nothing
   }


   @Override
   public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
   {
       Integer scrollY = getScrollY(view);

       // This will collapse the header when scrolling, until its height reaches
       // the toolbar height
       headerView.setTranslationY(Math.max(0, scrollY + minHeaderTranslation));

       // Scroll ratio (0 <= ratio <= 1). 
       // The ratio value is 0 when the header is completely expanded, 
       // 1 when it is completely collapsed
       float offset = 1 - Math.max(
           (float) (-minHeaderTranslation - scrollY) / -minHeaderTranslation, 0f);


       // Now that we have this ratio, we only have to apply translations, scales,
       // alpha, etc. to the header views

       // For instance, this will move the toolbar title & subtitle on the X axis 
       // from its original position when the ListView will be completely scrolled
       // down, to the Toolbar title position when it will be scrolled up.
       headerTitle.setTranslationX(toolbarTitleLeftMargin * offset);
       headerSubtitle.setTranslationX(toolbarTitleLeftMargin * offset);

       // Or we can make the FAB disappear when the ListView is scrolled 
       headerFab.setAlpha(1 - offset);
   }


   // Method that allows us to get the scroll Y position of the ListView
   public int getScrollY(AbsListView view)
   {
       View c = view.getChildAt(0);

       if (c == null)
           return 0;

       int firstVisiblePosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
       int top = c.getTop();

       int headerHeight = 0;
       if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1)
           headerHeight = this.headerHeight;

       return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
   }
   ```

Note that there are some parts of this code I didn't test, so feel free to highlight mistakes. But overall, I'm know that this solution works, even though I'm sure it can be improved.

**EDIT 2:**

There were some mistakes in the code above (that I didn't test until today...), so I changed a few lines to make it work :

1. I introduced another variable, minHeaderTranslation, which replaced minHeaderHeight;
2. I changed the Y translation value applied to the header View from :

   ```
       headerView.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY, minHeaderTranslation));
   ```

   to :

   ```
       headerView.setTranslationY(Math.max(0, scrollY + minHeaderTranslation));
   ```

   Previous expression wasn't working at all, I'm sorry about that...
3. The ratio calculation also changed, so that it now evolves from the bottom the toolbar (instead of the top of the screen) to the full expanded header.

Comment: Won't the header disappear once you scroll too far down? Afaik headers are recycled too, so even if you translate your header, so that it looks like it's pinned to the top, i think it would just disappear once the actual position moves out of sight.

Comment: You're right Kuno. I didn't try, but this is the expected behaviour. That's why I used a Toolbar inside a FrameLayout. The Main Content is ABOVE the toolbar with a marginTop of x. To play the animation I simply translate the Main Content between the Y axis

Comment: @FedeAmura Sweet, but I think the FAB is too low when it's at the bottom of the screen :)

Comment: Now everything is simpler with the new [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). You can achieve exactly this effect by following [this tutorial from Suleiman user](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/), based on the work of Chris Banes for the [Cheesesquare sample app](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare).<br><br>
**EDIT**<br>
Some users asked if they can use the same idea but with an icon. [Saulmm Github user tried something like that](https://github.com/saulmm

Comment: This library is a good approach to get the basic animation and bevaiour, but the CollapsingToolbarLayout does currently only support a string as title. No Icon or Subtitle.. Linked Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069107/how-to-show-toolbars-logo-icon-title-subtitle-when-wrapped-in-a-collapsingto

Comment: Not exactly the same, unfortunately. So to achieve the exact effect one should write it's own `CollapsingTitleWithIconAndSubtitleLayout` view, but wrapping listview (or recyclerview or nestedScrollableView) with `CoordinatorLayout` may give some benefits now

Answer (score 26):

Also check out `CollapsingTitleLayout` written by Chris Banes in Android team:
https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/J9Fwbc15BHN

[image]

Code: https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/91ac8a20acfbdc410a68

Comment: Excellent link my friend.

Answer (score 8):

Use design support library http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

include this in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'    
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.+'
```

for recycler view include this also

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

```
    <!-- AppBarLayout allows your Toolbar and other views (such as tabs provided by TabLayout) 
    to react to scroll events in a sibling view marked with a ScrollingViewBehavior.-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- specify tag app:layout_scrollFlags -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <!-- specify tag app:layout_scrollFlags -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <!--  app:layout_collapseMode="pin" will help to pin this view at top when scroll -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This will be your scrolling view. 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tag connects this features -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Your activity should extend **AppCompatActivity**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        //set toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

}
```

Your app theme should be like this

```
    <resources>
            <!-- Base application theme. -->   
            <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            </style>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Very nice, loving this design support lib

Comment: And I hate it. Changes all the time. Unfortunately I will have to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation:

`collapsedHeaderHeight` and `expandedHeaderHeight` are defined somewhere else, with the function `getAnimationProgress` I can get the Expand/Collapse progress, base on this value I do my animation and show/hide the real header.

```
  listForumPosts.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        /**
         * @return [0,1], 0 means header expanded, 1 means header collapsed
         */
        private float getAnimationProgress(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem) {
            if (firstVisibleItem > 0)
                return 1;

            // should not exceed 1
            return Math.min(
                    -view.getChildAt(0).getTop() / (float) (expandedHeaderHeight - collapsedHeaderHeight), 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // at render beginning, the view could be empty!
            if (view.getChildCount() > 0) {
                float animationProgress = getAnimationProgress(view, firstVisibleItem);
                imgForumHeaderAvatar.setAlpha(1-animationProgress);
                if (animationProgress == 1) {
                    layoutForumHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    layoutForumHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // do nothing
        }

    }
```