# How to make Toolbar animation like the Contacts app in Lollipop

Tags: android, animation, toolbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working on this app and I would like to implement the collapsing animation similar to the contacts app, I have not been able to find a tutorial that works with the Toolbar in the support library.

Here is a video showing the animation: http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWZ1F2b1pUOGFiZHc/patterns-scrollingtech-scrolling-070801_Flexible_Space_with_Image_xhdpi_002.webm

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app . Telegram does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below implements the action Expand / Collapse toolbar.

Basically we will have a
`CoordinatorLayout` (FrameLayout)
`AppBarLayout` (vertical LinearLayout Which implements many of the features of stuff designs),
`CollapsingToolbarLayout` (is a wrapper for Toolbar)
ImageView and Toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/logo"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr_container_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Observation
- FrameLayout is necessary app: layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
-TOOLBAR Not need backgroud, insert the color in the attribute app:contentScrim = "?Attr/ColorPrimary" from our CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

In your class

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("YourTitle");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but, in case someone still needs it, recently Google has released a new material design library that has this component. It is called CoordinatorLayout. A sample implementation is below:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fuurther info can be reached here: http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html