# Does Instagram use an actual ActionBar or a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, android-actionbar

If you go on the "Search" section on Instagram and you slowly scroll down, the Action Bar (if it is one) slowly scrolls to the top until it's gone. The tabs are still there (sticky/fixed). Is it an ActionBar and if so how did they do something like this?

I want the same function, so that if you scroll down the ListView, the Action Bar goes away at the same pace you scroll and the tabs under it are sticky.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question about something you'd like to do, or are you just kinda chewing the fat a little?

Comment: You can do it with `Toolbar`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app
This may be useful