# Flexible Space effect used in new Whatsapp app

Tags: android, scroll, material-design, whatsapp

I want to make a effect like when you are in the contact activity (after click on name of person in conversation) in the new Android Whatsapp app.

The Title and subtitle move from left to right and down to up until fix in the right position.

I'm using this lib: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView to get some Material Design effects in my app. And i'm using the example activity FlexibleSpaceWithImageListView to get something like what i really want.

Does someone know how to achiece the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram has the same effect and there is an excellent solution to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app)

Comment: Nice man. The example that you mentioned is very good. I used that to make things work here. :)