# Android: material design's Floating Action Button (FAB) and shifting views

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design, floating-action-button

I would like to implement two Material Design elements in Android:

- **the Floating Action Button (FAB)**
- "**shifting views**" (not sure if this is the proper term)

I cannot find any Android widget to implement **FAB**s. Which is the best recommended solution? is it to use third party libraries?

With "**shifting view**", I mean a view that shifts up and down. For example if you have two views in a fragment: top view which is fixed, and the bottom view which is a list, by scrolling the list, you can actually make the list take some space of the top view. How do you implement that? is it part of the Android framework or you need to use some third party libraries again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no stock Android implementation of **FAB**, but I've used this implementation of [**FAB's**](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) in couple of my projects and its working great and supports the material greatness!

so given the fact that there's no **FAB** implementation on Android, you should go for a 3rd party implementation

By shifting views do you mean like toolbar? Like similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app) or [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)? Its hard to say, now knowing exactly the use case or what do toy mean, but this is what your explanation reminds me of

Answer (score 1):

This one [here](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) might be pretty useful for any of the other material needed elements (widgets, dialogs, progress bars) and it also covers the FAB. As stated in the other answer, there is no default implementation so the solution would be to go for 3rd party libraries.

And [here](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) you can find different ways of implementing what you refer to as "shifting view". There is a demo app as well and it is easily customizable.