# Toolbar title disappears when adding views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I just realized that when I add views to the Toolbar in the xml file, the title disappears.

e.g.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_taskeditor_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/activity_taskeditor_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Without the views the title exists, but when adding my views it disappears.

Example image:

[image]

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show your Title with the EditText you have to Add a TextView for that and give TextAppearance `"@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_taskeditor_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
             android:text="@string/title"
             android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/activity_taskeditor_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is not a container so you should modify your code to look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_taskeditor_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/activity_taskeditor_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="JOA"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    //OTHER UI ELEMENTS HERE

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've added an image to the question. So this layout in said image is simply using a toolbar with a view on it's bottom with the same color?

Comment: Yes, they are fake toolbars. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27124857/2823516)