# Can't scroll ListView in its parent NestedScrollView - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, android-nestedscrollview

I am using `ListView` within `NestedScrollView`, but can't see more than 1 item in `ListView`. I can scroll upto the end of `TextView` (*textContact*) but can't scroll within the `ListView` (*listContact*).

Here's the code for .xml File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    ... >
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        ... >    
        <LinearLayout
            ...
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                ... />
            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                ... >
                <LinearLayout
                    ...
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textContact"
                        ... />
                    <LinearLayout
                        ...
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listContact"
                            ... />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ... />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Is there any design issue, any compatibility issue of the Widgets/Controls used here, or anything else ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable the following two properties inside the **NestedScrollView**,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Then use a helper class to extend the **ListView** width & fix scrolling functionality,

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Helper {
    public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            //do nothing return null
            return;
        }
        //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
      //setting listview item in adapter
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        // print height of adapter on log
        Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
    }
}
```

To use the helper class while setting the **ListView** adapter,

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
              Helper.getListViewSize(listView);
```

PS: Make sure you have added support design lib for your project.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Comment: which **LinearLayout** should have these properties ?
1. Above Toolbar
2. Below NestedScrollView
3. Outside ListView
Which LinearLayout ?

Comment: The one contains the ListView

Comment: It expanded the ListView from showing 1 item to multiple. But the problem is not solved yet. If the TextView is finished in about half of Screen size, then full ListView is visible. But if ListView is not visible at Activity Start, then it can't be scrolled. Only I am able to scroll is for the TextView and not for the ListView.

Comment: it's work for me when single line, but not work when multiple content in view.

Comment: Works perfectly. But it flicks on first load

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Use `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled()` on your `listview` and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have bad layout design and you should redesign it. In general, you shouldn't have a scrollable view like `ListView` inside another scrollable view like `NestedScrollView` or `ScrollView`. Do you really need that? Try to change it, flatten your views structure and this problem should disappear.

Comment: Yes I want company's info and then custom ListView for social buttons, instead of adding buttons for each social network. So it would be better if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:clipToPadding="false" >
       </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Are you missing app:layout_behavior

Comment: **Firstly,**  I am not using RecyclerView, and **Second**, by adding that property, only ListView is now expanded. But if it gets out of Screen at Activity Startup, then I can't see full ListView by scrolling, again only first item is visible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app