# How to achieve an "animated CollapsingToolbar?"

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Basically, I am wondering how when using a RecyclerView, how one can achieve a sort of "animated CollapsingToolbar." Note it's in quotes, because I'm not attached to the solution being a CollapsingToolbar, however that's the closest thing I can find so far to what I want. Basically, I want to make a toolbar that has the title of my app, and a subtitle with some string followed by an int (as a string type). As I scroll up, I want the string to fade off, but have the int remain and move up to the same level as the app title.

[image] (Excuse the crude drawing)

I've looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app), however it's dependent on a ListView. I've also looked at [this solution](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/), however I can't see how I would be able to customize the animation how I'd like. [This repo](https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar) looks like it could work, but it has a bunch of errors and can't get it to compile.

So basically, to sum it up, I'm looking for how it's possible to animate a toolbar in the way I've described above, *with any means you think are best*, not necesserily a CollapsingToolbar.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @skydroid I don't have anything that works at all like what I'm trying to achieve. The closest I have gotten is the two provided links, as well as the reasons why they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this [CoordinatorLayout](https://github.com/melvinjlobo/Collapsible-Toolbar-Helper)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

        <abysmel.com.collapsibletoolbarhelper.widgets.CollapsibleToolbarHelper
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            >

            <!--Note that the position has to be set with respect to the collapsed toolbar. So,
                aligning it in center initially (centerInParent="true") will NOT work as it will remain
                at its position even after the Toolbar collapses. Also note that the initially set the
                alpha of the view to zero and NOT the visibility to gone, as the view will then have never
                been drawn which will throw all calculations haywire for show_on_collapse. Wish there
                was a better way to do this-->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/hello.img"
                android:src="@mipmap/hello"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:alpha="0"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent = "3%"
                app:collapseMode="show_on_collapse"/>

            <!-- Title -->
            <abysmel.com.collapsibletoolbarhelper.widgets.CollapsibleTextLayout
                android:id="@+id/hello.text"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:layout_widthPercent="59%"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent = "1%"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent = "1%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:collapseMode="pin_on_scroll"
                app:textToShow = "Hello World"
                app:expandedTextColor = "@android:color/white"
                app:collapsedTextColor = "@android:color/white"
                app:typefaceFamilyPrimary = "sans-serif-light"
                app:typefaceFamilySecondary = "sans-serif-medium"
                app:isMultiFaceted="true"
                app:typefaceSplitPosition="5"
                app:expandedTextSize = "62dp"
                app:collapsedTextSize = "32dp"
                app:maxExpandedTextSize = "62dp"
                />

            <!-- The hello number edit button -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hello.edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent = "3%"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent = "1%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent = "4%"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/pencil"
                app:collapseMode="hide_on_collapse"/>

            <!-- The hello Number -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello.number"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent = "1%"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent = "1%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent = "1%"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/hello.edit"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hello.text"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/hello_no_sign"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/hello_no_size"
                app:collapseMode="pin_on_scroll"/>



            <!-- Version -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/version"
                app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/hello.text"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                android:text="@string/version"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/version_no_size"
                app:collapseMode="parallax_on_scroll"
                 />

            <!-- E-mail Address -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello.address"
                app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/hello.number"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="end"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="5%"
                android:text="@string/emailaddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mail_address_size"
                app:collapseMode="parallax_on_scroll"
                 />
        </abysmel.com.collapsibletoolbarhelper.widgets.CollapsibleToolbarHelper>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar

Comment: Looks like it could work, but I can't seem to figure out how to install it. It looks like it's an android app in itself, not really a library

Comment: Yeah, it appears that this library is outdated. I found a grade for it, but it is riddled with errors and appears to be for 24.1.1 at the moment, but even using that version of design it throws ResourceNotFoundExceptions