# Android AlertDialog with Expands/Collapse Animation?

Tags: android

I have alertdialog which is showing on x,y position of one of view in my recycleview. dialog position is changing as row number is increased.

When I put below file for animation, dialog shows from top to y position of my alert dialog. what i want to show it from y position to slide down.

As Like as when you click on your facebook comment, it asks to copy, edit, delete or cancel in dialog.

I gone through many animation file but dialog shows from top to y position and when i close it goes from y position to top.

my animation file:

slide_out_bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false"
    >

  <translate
      android:duration="@integer/dialogplus_animation_default_duration"
      android:fromXDelta="0%"
      android:fromYDelta="0%"
      android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:toYDelta="100%"
      />
</set>
```

i checked this one but doesn't work:

[Android: Expand/collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation)

[Expand/Collapse Lollipop toolbar animation (Telegram app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app)